# How to call WASI functions directly in C using wasi-sdk (import module problem)

Tags: c, webassembly, wasi

I'm trying to call a WASI function (fd_write) directly in a C program using [wasi-sdk](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk). This is the the library (lib.c):

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct Ciovec
{
    uint8_t *buf;
    uint32_t buf_len;
};

uint16_t fd_write(uint32_t fd, struct Ciovec *iovs_ptr, uint32_t iovs_len, uint32_t *nwritten);

static char *str = "just testing\n";

void c_main()
{
    struct Ciovec vec = { .buf = (uint8_t*)str, .buf_len = 13 };
    uint32_t nwritten = 0;
    fd_write(1, &vec, 1, &nwritten);
}
```

Now if I build this to a statically-linkable library using wasi-sdk

```
~/wasi-sdk-11.0/bin/clang --sysroot ~/wasi-sdk-11.0/share/wasi-sysroot/ lib.c -c -o lib.o -fpic
```

I get this wat: (`wasm2wat --enable-all` output)

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func))
  (type (;1;) (func (param i32 i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "__linear_memory" (memory (;0;) 1))
  (import "env" "__indirect_function_table" (table (;0;) 0 funcref))
  (import "env" "__stack_pointer" (global (;0;) (mut i32)))
  (import "env" "fd_write" (func (;0;) (type 1)))
  ...)
```

Now this import line for `fd_write` is not correct. As far as I understand WASI functions need to be imported from `wasi_snapshot_preview1` or `wasi_unstable` (I don't have a source for the first one, I just saw it in an open-source code, for the second see the example [here](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime/blob/main/docs/WASI-tutorial.md#web-assembly-text-example), but I'm not sure how to do then in C. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in [wasi-libc](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-libc) [source code](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-libc/blob/00cc5944dfc8c85ab5c5bee4cdef221afa2121f7/libc-bottom-half/headers/public/wasi/api.h#L2163-L2184):

```
uint16_t fd_write(uint32_t fd, struct Ciovec *iovs_ptr, uint32_t iovs_len, uint32_t *nwritten)
    __attribute__((
                __import_module__("wasi_snapshot_preview1"),
                __import_name__("fd_write"),
                ));
```

Generated Wasm:

```
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_write" (func $fd_write (type 1)))
```

This still doesn't work though, I get `undefined symbol: fd_write` errors, but at least I know how to specify the import path now.

Comment: Have you progressed since ? I'm trying to do the same thing but with a custom function.

Answer (score 2):

So I made this to work:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern uint16_t my_func()
__attribute__((
    __import_module__("my_module"),
    __import_name__("my_func"),
));

int main(){
    my_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `-Wl,--allow-undefined`

Generates

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;1;) (func (param i32 i64 i32) (result i64)))
  (type (;2;) (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;3;) (func (result i32)))
  (type (;4;) (func (param i32)))
  (type (;5;) (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;6;) (func (param i32 i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;7;) (func (param i32 i64 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;8;) (func))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "fd_prestat_get" (func $__wasi_fd_prestat_get (type 2)))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "fd_prestat_dir_name" (func $__wasi_fd_prestat_dir_name (type 0)))
  (import "my_module" "my_func" (func $my_func__ (type 3)))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "proc_exit" (func $__wasi_proc_exit (type 4)))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "fd_fdstat_get" (func $__wasi_fd_fdstat_get (type 2)))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "fd_close" (func $__wasi_fd_close (type 5)))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "fd_write" (func $__wasi_fd_write (type 6)))
  (import "wasi_unstable" "fd_seek" (func $__wasi_fd_seek (type 7)))
  (func $__wasm_call_ctors (type 8))
  (func $undefined:__wasilibc_populate_environ (type 3) (result i32)
```